# How do I call a function in C# that adds text to your existing code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, function

This is the C# code that I am using for my program:

```
    string foo = "boogie";

    string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"+foo+".xml";

        using (StreamWriter fv = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            fv.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\r\n");
            fv.WriteLine("<asx:abap xmlns:asx = \"http://www.awebsite.com\" version = \"1.0\">\r\n");
            fv.WriteLine("<asx:values>\r\n");
            fv.WriteLine("<HANDLINGUNIT>\r\n");
        }
```

and I am basically trying to do this:

```
    string foo = "boogie";

    string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"+foo+".xml";

        using (StreamWriter fv = File.AppendText(path))
        {
        XMLHeader();
        fv.WriteLine("HANDLINGUNIT> \r\n");
        }

Private Void XMLHeader();
            {
        *pseudocode for my question*
         convert this to string:
     fv.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\r\n");
     fv.WriteLine("<asx:abap xmlns:asx = \"http://www.awebsite.com\" version = \"1.0\">\r\n");
     fv.WriteLine("<asx:values>\r\n");
     }
```

That way, when I call that function, it will be as if the lines of code were written in the above code. I hope this all makes sense!

Comment: Use XML serialization. There are dozens of ways to manipulate XML that are better than hand-writing strings.

Comment: @DanielMann I agree with you wholeheartedly, and I wish I could. However for this application, this is how they would like me to approach this, unfortunately.

Comment: **Why?!?** That's ridiculous!

Comment: If you add 'StreamWriter fv' as parameter for the XMLHeader function then you have the desired outcome.

Comment: You already have invalid xml "fv.WriteLine("HANDLINGUNIT> \r\n");", which is why you should use xml serialization. Or at least an xml class like XmlDocument or XDocument.

Comment: @DanielMann It is pretty ridiculous! But I am just a peon and I don't make the rules. It is a conversion from C code written by another person. Since their code was written in that style, line by line, so this one will be as well =\

Comment: `Jimmie N` who is `They` are you the developer or are you not standing / holding your ground on this .. generally speaking if you  are coding this and it gives them the expected outcome, then how can they ; as you put it, tell you how to approach it in regards to coding..? I am just curious.. Perhaps you can tell the individual that there are many ways to skin a cat..peon or not..

Comment: @ShellShock Theres a closing tag for <HANDLINGUNIT>, I just didnt include it in the code above =p

Comment: @DJKRAZE its one of those instances where for this moment, this is the process, when revision comes, I will able to try again. But I am not able to divulge for whom. Thank you for your concern, but thats just the way it is sometimes.

Comment: makes no sense.. anyway try to maintain the level of thinking outside the box and whom ever it is that is giving you direction I hope that they understand that the way things are done or were done in `C` are definitely not the same in `C# or any other .NET Language` good luck

Comment: @JimmieN you should at least explain your viewpoint on this and *why* this is not the best way to move forward. Don't just do something in a messy way just because you think that's what they want, could be whoever is making these decisions doesn't realize there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I do understand the question, but if I've got it right, you call a function something like the following. You need to pass 'fv' as an argument to the XMLHeader function.

```
string foo = "boogie";

string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"+foo+".xml";

using (StreamWriter fv = File.AppendText(path))
{
    XMLHeader(fv);
    fv.WriteLine("HANDLINGUNIT> \r\n");
}

Private Void XMLHeader(StreamWriter fv)
{
    // *pseudocode for my question*
    // convert this to string:
    fv.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\r\n");
    fv.WriteLine("<asx:abap xmlns:asx = \"http://www.awebsite.com\" version = \"1.0\">\r\n");
    fv.WriteLine("<asx:values>\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
string foo = "boogie";

string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\"+foo+".xml";

using (StreamWriter fv = File.AppendText(path))
{
    fv.WriteLine(getXMLHeader());       
    fv.WriteLine("<HANDLINGUNIT> \r\n");
}

private string getXMLHeader()
{
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\r\n" +
           "<asx:abap xmlns:asx = \"http://www.awebsite.com\" version = \"1.0\">\r\n" +
           "<asx:values>\r\n";
}
```